# I'm getting an error in pyscopg2 library (python) ERROR:root:connection to server at "localhost", port 5432 failed: FATAL: database does not exist

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, fatal-error

I'm getting "ERROR:root:connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  database "CONSUMER_EXPENDITURES" does not exist" . Below is my code snippet

`def create_database():
try:
conn_consumer_expenditures = None

```
    conn_postgres = psycopg2.connect("dbname=postgres user=postgres password=1234")

    conn_postgres.set_isolation_level(ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)

    conn_postgres.set_session(autocommit=True)
    
    cursor_postgres = conn_postgres.cursor()

    cursor_postgres.execute("DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS CONSUMER_EXPENDITURES")

    cursor_postgres.execute("CREATE DATABASE CONSUMER_EXPENDITURES")
    
    conn_postgres.commit()
    
    conn_postgres.close()

    time.sleep(2)
    
    conn_consumer_expenditures = psycopg2.connect("dbname=CONSUMER_EXPENDITURES user=postgres password=1234")

    conn_consumer_expenditures.set_isolation_level(ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)

    conn_consumer_expenditures.set_session(autocommit=True)
    
    cursor_consumer_expenditures = conn_consumer_expenditures.cursor()

    return conn_consumer_expenditures, cursor_consumer_expenditures

except Exception as e:
    if conn_consumer_expenditures:
        conn_consumer_expenditures.rollback()
    logging.error(msg=str(e))`
```

I was trying to create a new database 'CONSUMER_EXPENDITURES' . But even after creating the db I'm getting database doesn't exist.

Comment: Does your username have permission to create a new database?

Comment: @TimRoberts , yes the username has permission.I have created multiple other database with this username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can pro problem with case sensitivity. postgres use lower case notation by default. Try:

```
psycopg2.connect("dbname=consumer_expenditures user=postgres password=1234")
```